# Авторизация на сервере и перехват куков

Tags: http, cookie, веб-сервер, https

Подскажите пожалуйста,вот экспериментирую в хроме с подменой http-заголовков запроса, а именно заголовков "Cookie".

То есть сначала захожу на сайт, авторизуюсь, сайт соответственно выдает мне куки авторизации.
Закрываю браузер, отрываю опять сайт и я там автоматически авторизован.
То есть, как я понимаю - это работают куки авторизации.

Теперь я опять закрываю браузер, опять открываю сайт, но теперь перехватываю во всех запросах в которых присутствует заголовок "Cookie" и заменяю тело куки на просто произвольные каракули. Однако, страница все равно открывается с моей авторизацией.

Но, как это возможно ? Как сайт понимает, что это я ?

**Заголовки запроса:**

```
Request_GetMethod:GET
Request_GetReferrerPolicy:0
Request_GetResourceType:RT_MAIN_FRAME


Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Request_vector_GetHeaderMap: Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie:cookie_bla_bla
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36
```

**Ответ на этот запрос:**

```
Response_GetCharset:utf-8
Response_GetMimeType:text/html

cache-control:private
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Tue, 21 Jun 2022 05:46:24 GMT
pragma:private
server:ddos-guard
set-cookie:cforig_cookieuser=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; secure
set-cookie:cfsessionhash=e59f13677f46886b46fe96afeae8db67; path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie:cfdup_timestamp=1655790384
x-powered-by:PHP/5.6.31
```

И html страница, которая приходит на этот запрос, уже содержит мои данные авторизации.

Я не могу понять, как сайт может идентифицировать меня, если в запросе нет авторизационной информации.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее на момент подмены кукисов. Скорее всего вы ошиблись, и на сайт отправляются реальные куки, поэтому сайт вас авторизует. Также, если речь про API, там часто используются не куки, а Bearer-авторизация, и токен передается в другом заголовке. Приведите пример всего запроса, с заголовками, чтобы был предметный разговор.

Comment: @Total Pusher, в исходящих заголовках только cookie, заголовка по типу Authorization или что то подобное нет. Мистика какая то.

Comment: Покажите пример того, что реально отправляется. Вкладка сеть, щелкаете на запрос правой кнопкой мышки, copy as curl. Там будет то, что было отправлено. Покажите это. Также посмотрите, не берется ли ответ из кеша - там будет пометка "from disk cache" - как-то так.

Comment: @Total Pusher, добавил в описание.

Comment: Сделайте copy as curl. Затем вставьте в консоль. Убедитесь, что заголовок Cookie действительно такой. Также убедитесь, что другого заголовка Cookie нет (да-да, можно отправить несколько одноименных заголовков). Затем выполните это в консоли. Ожидается, что будет страница входа, то есть без авторизации.